# Circle Hover Area in IE7

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-7

how can I make circle hover area what will work in IE7?

I made example with border-radius but it is not work for IE7: http://jsfiddle.net/y4xpQ

Thx

Comment: I don't believe you can pre-CSS3. Try a transparent circle in an imagemap. That could probably do it.

Comment: See CSS compatibility for IE http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

pretty sure you cant. The item is displayed as block(think of it as a brick).  Not as circle.  Sorry

but if you are after the border radius in ie7 look here - http://css3pie.com/

Comment: I believe Andrew is correct. If you want a clickable circle in an image however, take a look at the <area> and <map> tags ^^

Answer (score 1):

If you're targeting "old" browsers you might want to take a look at the also very old <area>.
Not the best element to use when it comes to accessibility (or standards compliance if you're after a circle made with shape="circ") but in this case i guess it gets the job done.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/area

Comment: yes, but how can i make change ti different image when i hover on area, cause hover works only for anchor in IE7

Comment: The <area> is just to make a certain area respond to user interactions like click and hover, so with the underlaying image you can do anything you want.
Like make it react to hovers through CSS or JavaScript.
In this case i would advise using JavaScript because the older IE's dont do :hover on anything but <a>